# Unexpected return value in this C program

Tags: c, algorithm, initialization, max, min

I wrote a C program to find the difference in indices of the largest even number and the smallest even number in an array(here 0 is considered as an even number and from the testcases it definitely didn't look like the array should be sorted). It will return a value or No if the array has one element or no even numbers in that array.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {
  
    int n,small,big,a[50],b1,s1,diff;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    


    
    small = a[0];
    big = a[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < small && a[i]%2 == 0)
        {
            small = a[i];
            s1 = i;
        }
        if (a[i] > big && a[i]%2 == 0)
        {
            big = a[i];
            b1 = i;
        }
    }
    diff = b1-s1;
    
    if(diff==0){
      printf("NO");
    }
    else{
      printf("%d",diff);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I give as input

```
4
120 0 4 7
```

It doesn't return 1 . It returns 32657.
What logic am I not understanding here? Please help me.

Comment: Since your question is about C please do not tag C++ as the solution will differ.

Comment: You are not initializing all of your variables. If there were no even numbers in the array, then `s1` and `b1` would end up with *indeterminate* values, causing *undefined behavior* for the `diff` calculation.

Comment: What happens if `a[0]` is not an even number? It's probably better to treat the first element like all other elements and initialize `b1` and `s1` to −1 to mean: no even element seen so far. Your condition for printing NO should reflect that.

Comment: I suspect you mean "output" rather than "return".

Comment: @FredLarson Thank you for pointing it out. I have removed it.

Comment: @MOehm It is actually a really good idea. It didn't cross my mind before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
small = a[0];
big = a[0];
```

you also need to initialize `s1` and `b1`

```
s1 = 0;
b1 = 0;
```

In general your approach is incorrect because a[0] can be an odd number and can be the greatest or smallest number in the array.

So at first you need to find in the array  the first even number and if such a number exists (for example at index i) then write

```
small = a[i];
big = a[i];
s1 = i;
b1 = i;
```

Pay attention to that you can include the header `<stdio.h>` in fact in any place in your program because after the first inclusion of the header all other headers will not be actually included. But do not do that because it makes your program very strange.:)

So remove this directive in main

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Also the directive

```
#include <math.h>
```

is redundant because neither declaration from the header is used in your program. You may also remove it.